# How can I create a GVariant* to feed to g_variant_iter_new?

Tags: c, glib, gio, gvariant

The following simple code is sufficient to reproduce the error I am having.

```
#include <gio/gio.h>

int main()
{
    GVariantIter *Iter;
    const gchar* s = "[('appname', uint64 size, uint64 field, false)]";
    GVariant* up = g_variant_new_string(s);
    Iter = g_variant_iter_new(up);
    return 0;
}
```

It is resulting in:

> GLib:ERROR:../../../glib/gvariant-serialiser.c:1367:g_variant_serialised_n_children: code should not be reached
> Bail out! GLib:ERROR:../../../glib/gvariant-serialiser.c:1367:g_variant_serialised_n_children: code should not be reached
> Aborted

What am I missing? [The documentation](https://people.gnome.org/%7Edesrt/glib-docs/glib-GVariant.html) is somewhat vague.

[g_variant_new_string ()](https://people.gnome.org/%7Edesrt/glib-docs/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-new-string)

```
GVariant * g_variant_new_string (const gchar *string);
Creates a string GVariant with the contents of string.
```

---

[g_variant_iter_new ()](https://people.gnome.org/%7Edesrt/glib-docs/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-iter-new)

```
GVariantIter * g_variant_iter_new (GVariant *value);
Creates a heap-allocated GVariantIter for iterating over the items in value.
```

Comment: I barely used `GVariants` so far... but isn't it supposed to be a container that you create an iterator for? I don't think you can iterate over a string.

Comment: Precisely, `GVariantIter` is for iterating over containers (arrays, dictionaries and tuples). What did you think iterating over a string would do?

Comment: @PhilipWithnall the string I am receiving is an actual array. I provided a dummy example. The one I get is in the format: `[('appname', uint64 size, uint64 field, gboolean)]` I was hoping instead of breaking the raw string, to create a GVariant to iter over it.

Comment: If the string is in the format exported by `g_variant_print()`, then you can use `g_variant_parse()` to parse it into a `GVariant*`. Without a minimal reproducer of the code you’re trying to get working then I can’t be sure, though.